# make "$arr = Foo::bar(); $v = $arr[$i]" into one line of code

Tags: php

I run into a special situation that needs to make

```
$arr = Foo::bar();
$v = $arr[$i]
```

into one line of code. `$v = Foo::bar()[$i]` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible with PHP at the minute, although I do believe it's being added for the next PHP version. Here's some more information on the subject:

http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html

I can't wait for this to be added too.

Comment: What is not possible? There is no dereferencing, but it is possible to do.

Comment: I was commenting on their example.

Answer (score 1):

How's this? Exactly what you wanted? =P

```
$v = Foo::barElement(0);
```

and...

```
class Foo
{
    public static function barElement($index) {$t = self::bar(); return $t[$index];}

    public static function bar......
}
```

Comment: Indeed. There is no any reason to return more data, than it is strongly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
$v = reset(Foo::bar());
```

Comment: In my case, it is actually an associative array.

Comment: @powerboy: that is why it is important to ask specific and precise question, not anything similar to it.

Answer (score 0):

Array derefencing is not yet implemented in the current versions of PHP. You'll have to wait until PHP 5.4 or 6.0 are released.